# add new derived field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I would like to add a new field `loctype` to the existing index `ymetrics` so that the new field will have the value of existing field `location` like below.

```
ctx._source.location.substring(0, ctx._source.location.indexOf(1,\"/\"))"
```

I tried below, but it seems like is interpreted completely differently and adds a new record with id "_update"

```
POST /ymetrics/request/_update
{
  "script": "ctx._source.loctype = ctx._source.location.substring(0, ctx._source.location.indexOf(1,\"/\"))"
}
```

How can I add a new `field` that will update all existing `documents` with new field value. And also whenever a new document is added, this new field will have the value from other field as derived with `expression` above ?

The reason behind this is that I cannot change the 3rd party library that creates the `document` and neither the value of the existing `field` while inserting from source. So I need this new `field` that will have value according my to needs to put some charts.

I'm using elasticsearch 2.x version, so the `script field` does not take any other type than `number`.

After using `_update_by_query` as below, throws parse exception.

**query:**

```
POST /ymetrics/_update_by_query
{
  "script": "ctx._source.loctype = doc['resource'].substring(0, doc['location'].indexOf(1,'/'))"
  "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

**error:**

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse content to map"
         }
      ],
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse content to map",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "json_parse_exception",
         "reason": "Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.ChannelBufferStreamInput@34ceed6e; line: 3, column: 4]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Comment: You're missing an ID in your URL `/ymetrics/request/<DOC_ID>/_update`

Comment: Thanks Val. I need to update for all documents. The document id is auto generated one in my index. Should wildcard `* ` work ?

Comment: Then you need to use the `_update_by_query` endpoint

Comment: Ok I see. Should I need match_all() query? or by default it updates all documents?

Comment: Yes you need the match_all query

Comment: I couldn't escape the double quotes in `indexOf` and throws `ParseException`. any ideas ? Please find update in the question.

Comment: why not simply using single quotes?

Comment: i tried already. error : "Unrecognized character escape ''' (code 39)\n

Comment: Can you show what you tried? make sure not to escape the single quote

Comment: pls see update.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around: `indexOf('/', 1)` ?

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that there is additional comma and had to change as "inline".